# Efficiently accessing all files from a multi part form in python Flask

Tags: python, forms, flask

I'm using Python Flask for backend. I have a form that lets a user upload two audio files and I join the files in the backend. If both files are uploaded at once after pressing 'submit' then in the back end, I can access them using:

```
files = [request.files['filename-1'],
                 request.files['filename-2']]
```

But if I make it use "multipart/form-data", how do I access files when each file is uploaded one at a time? What is a good way to wait in the backend for the same user to upload the second file, so that I can beginning joining them? Loop?

Note: I don't have control over the form's design as someone else is building it.